# Extracting text between double quotation marks in R

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning, stringr

I have a cell with text ["bestsellers","mysteries_thrillers_true_crime","science_fiction_fantasy","literary_fiction"]

The desired outcome is all the types in the cell:

```
    [1]"bestsellers"
    [2]"mysteries_thrillers_true_crime" 
    [3]"science_fiction_fantasy"
    [4]"literary_fiction"
```

To extract the text between the double quotation marks, I tried

```
str_extract(data$preferences[1], "\\[\".*?\"\\]")
```

and

```
str_extract(data$preferences[1], "\".*?\"")
```

both got the result:

```
 [1] "[\"bestsellers\",\"mysteries_thrillers_true_crime\",\"science_fiction_fantasy\",\"literary_fiction\"]
```

My question is how to get rid of the [ and ] and get the desire outcome?

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON('["bestsellers","mysteries_thrillers_true_crime","science_fiction_fantasy","literary_fiction"]')`

Comment: Do _not_ use regex here, use a JSON parser/library instead, q.v. the above comment.

Comment: @rrrcr Clarification required. Do you want to get a regex for extracting only the text between double quotes contained in this string - ["bestsellers","mysteries_thrillers_true_crime","science_fiction_fantasy","literary_fiction"] ?